# Install php7.0 in ubuntu 15.10 Wily

Tags: apt, 15.10, php, php7

How can I install php7.0 on this Ubuntu 15.10?

I'm trying to run:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y software-properties-common

LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update -y
```

`apt-cache search php7` finds nothing:

```
root@b4d3279c42b1:/# apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

Running this inside docker, based on Ubuntu:15.10

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
  software-properties-common

RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
    php7.0 \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppa's are not official means of software distribution. As such, they are up to whomever created them to maintain the releases they wish to support.

In this case, the [ondrej/php ppa does not include Wily packages](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150). You'll need to upgrade to 16.04 if you wish to use this PPA or compile php 7.0 yourself (not recommended)

Comment: If you move to `FROM ubuntu:16.04` this should work fine.

Comment: This is simplified example unfortunately. My dockerfile is based on two underlying images not maintained by me. The bottom one is `FROM ubuntu:15.10` so I'll have to rebuild it probably all from scratch